# Ensure user can only run the reports in a report folder but not save any reports to that folder

Tags: reporting, custom-profile, access, reports-folder

We are trying to limit a users access so they can run all of the reports in a given folder, but they cannot edit the reports in the folder nor can they save any new reports to that folder.

So far we have managed to give them view access to the folder, prevent them from modifying the pre-configured reports in the folder but we cannot stop them from adding new reports into the same folder.

Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

Viewer access in folder level doesn't prevent users from cloning or creating new reports. They cannot change existing report.

Refer: [Viewer Access Levels to Report and Dashboard Folders](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=analytics_folder_viewer.htm&type=0) documentation

> With Viewer access you can see the data in a report or dashboard, but you can’t make any changes, except by cloning it into a new report or dashboard. All users have at least Viewer access to report and dashboard folders that have been shared with them. (Some users may have administrative user permissions that give them greater access.)

Also, if you remove `Create and Customize Reports` permission from profile or permission set then user will not be able to create any reports. So it has consequences. Refer [User Permissions for Sharing Reports and Dashboards](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=analytics_sharing_permissions.htm&language=en_US&type=0)

*So, prevention of report creation on folder level cannot be accomplished.*